# convergence of a method

Tags: finite-element, reference-request

I  want to show convergence of a finite element  method for a higher order equation.I have a coupled equations that solved together and gives two variables as answer $[u, v]$.
$$w+\Delta u=0$$
$$\Delta w=f$$
for finding the answer
$$[u,w]=K^{-1}F,$$
Unfortunately, I am really confused about that and have a lot of questions such as:
What space should I used?  Should I show convergence for both of variables together or separately?
If I have a bilinear form what do I need to show (boundedness, coercively and so existence, uniqueness )?

Does anyone know a good reference that I can find my answers?

Comment: What you describe is called the "mixed method for the biharmonic equation". Try searching the literature for these terms.